# Изменить массив

Tags: php

Как можно изменить этот массив:

```
array(2) { 
   [0]=> array(1) { ["tag"]=> string(1) "3" } 
   [1]=> array(1) { ["tag"]=> string(1) "2" } 
}
```

На вот такой:

```
array(2) { [0]=> int(3) [1]=> int(2) }
```

Comment: array_column(), array_map()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = array_map(function($v){ return +$v['tag'];}, $data)
```

либо

```
$result = array_map('int', array_column($data, 'tag'));
```